# Reversing the characters of each individual word of a sentence without reversing the word order

Tags: java, arrays, loops, stack

I have this code that is supposed to do what the title said, reverse the order of characters without changing the order of the words:

```
package stackTests;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;


public class StackTest
{
  Stack<Character> stack;

  public StackTest()
  {
    stack = new Stack<Character>();
  }

  public String reverseString(String str)
  {
    int start = 0;
    int start2 = 0;
    int size;
    char space = ' ';
    char[] cArr;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(str);
    cArr = str.toCharArray();
    for (; start < cArr.length; start++)
    {
      if(cArr[start] == space || start == cArr.length - 1)
      {
        for (; start2 < stack.size(); start++)
        {
          System.out.print(stack.pop());
        }
      }
      else
      {
        stack.push(cArr[start]);
      }
      start2 = 0;
    }
    return str;
  }
}
```

It works fine if I enter a single word like "Hello"--it will output "olleH"--but as soon as it gets more complicated than one word it starts to output some weird things."Hello my name is" outputs "ollehem". I'm really new to `Stack`s and this is my first time using them. I'm not sure if there is a logic error or improper use of `Stack`s.

Comment: That's not readable. Format your code in a readable way.

Comment: Do you really have to use a Stack? Is this part of the homework?

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Possibly related (code golf): https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11142/reverse-each-word-in-a-line-of-text-while-keeping-the-order-of-the-words-and-ca

Comment: I don't see where the stack fits in your problem. I would go like 1) Split the sentence into words using String#split, 2) Reverse each element and add it to a list in order, 3) Put back the words together.

Comment: The only problem is I have to use stacks for an assignment, also how is my code not readable... @m0skit0

Comment: @JadenHambley Lack of proper indentation. See the answers below for proper indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're not outputting original spaces, this is why you're seeing strange results

here is fixed version:

```
public static void reverseString(final String str) {
    final Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        final char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == ' ') {
            while (!stack.isEmpty())
                System.out.print(stack.pop());
            System.out.print(' ');
        } else
            stack.push(c);
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty())
        System.out.print(stack.pop());
}
```

another version without stack, with in-place replacement:

```
public static void reverseString(final String str) {
    final char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == ' ') {
            reverse(chars, start, i - 1);
            start = i + 1;
        }
    }
    reverse(chars, start, chars.length - 1);
    System.out.println(new String(chars));
}

private static void reverse(final char[] chars, int s, int e) {
    while (s < e) {
        final char t = chars[s];
        chars[s] = chars[e];
        chars[e] = t;
        s++;
        e--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I was just  over thinking it with using an array, don't know why i thought that was a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you HAVE to use a stack, I would follow an algorithm like this:

```
String myString = "Hello World";
Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String[] splitString = myString.split(" ");

//Iterate through each word in the string
for(String s : splitString){

    //Push each character of the word into LIFO stack
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
        stack.push(c);
    }

    //Build new string with reverse ordered characters
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        sb.append(stack.pop());
    }

    //Append a space as long as it's not the last word of the original string
    if(!s.equals(splitString[splitString.length - 1]))
        sb.append(" ");
}

//Print the new string
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

I'm not sure efficiency matters to you, but this algorithm would work in linear time, where n is the number of characters in the string.

Comment: Could you possibly break down your process a little bit for me as I'm not quite familiar with StringBuilder, so I'm a little lost.

Comment: Absolutely. A string in java is an immutable object. This means that when you add to a string, it's actually creating a brand new string in memory, not just adding onto the previous one. StringBuilder is an object that allows you do safely (memory speaking) append new strings to your StringBuilder object. For your purposes, you can also use a plain String object (Just replace the StringBuilder with String myString = "", and replace the append statements with myString += stack.pop()).

Comment: Okay I see, thank you for the explanation cleared it up completely!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in-place without using any extra space (Not using stack):

```
public class ReverseWordsInplace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reverseWords(new StringBuilder("This is a test"));
    }

    public static void reverseWords(StringBuilder s) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(s);
        int startWordIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' || str.length() - 1 == i) {
                int x = 0;
                int endWordIndex = str.charAt(i) == ' ' ? i - 1 : i;
                while (endWordIndex - x > startWordIndex + x) {
                    char c1 = str.charAt(startWordIndex + x);
                    char c2 = str.charAt(endWordIndex - x);
                    str.setCharAt(startWordIndex + x, c2);
                    str.setCharAt(endWordIndex - x, c1);
                    x++;
                }
                startWordIndex = i + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output:

> sihT si a tset